# PostgreSQL find surrounding values

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, window-functions

I have a set of positions at discrete points in time. I would like to use a function that will return the positions with the first smaller and the first higher timestamp.

E.g.

```
timestamp | pos
5         | (-3, -3)
10        | (0, 0)
15        | (3, 3)
20        | (6, 6)
```

If I query this table for the timestamp 17, I would get the rows

```
15        | (3, 3)
20        | (6, 6)
```

I'm expecting something like

```
SELECT * FROM positions WHERE timestamp = first_smaller(17)
SELECT * FROM positions WHERE timestamp = first_greater(17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from positions where timestamp <= 17 order by timestamp desc limit 1;
```

and

```
select * from positions where timestamp >= 17 order by timestamp asc limit 1;
```

Comment: Yep, and you can `UNION` them together as subqueries to get the result in a single logical query. Not that it makes tons of difference.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM positions 
 WHERE timestamp = (SELECT max(timestamp) FROM position WHERE timestamp <= 17))
UNION
(SELECT * 
 FROM positions 
 WHERE timestamp = (SELECT min(timestamp) FROM position WHERE timestamp >= 17))
```